# background-attachment: local in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

Is there any way to produce the effect of `background-attachment: local` in Firefox? For some bizarre reason it doesn't support it...

Comment: What is this “`background-image:local`” supposed to be?

Comment: In your title you said `background-position`, in your question you said `background-image`, and I think you actually mean `background-attachment`. Is this the case? :)

Comment: I understand the question, but it doesn't make much sense. You have to apply the path to the image in CSS, regardless if it's local or not.

Comment: For those still clueless after the edit: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-attachment

Comment: @rynah: Yeah I would have assumed the same. It's the only background property + value that only Firefox doesn't understand while all other browsers do. (Chrome on the other hand is the only one that doesn't understand `background-position: <length> <xpos> <length> <ypos>`.)

Comment: I'm surprised that people downvoted my obvious lapse in concentration, rather than just editing it to what was obviously intended... Thanks rynah

Comment: No problem. It might be better to look at the situation, though. Knowning the type of stuff you work on, is the `local` critical? There might be a better way to structure it.

Comment: Coming soon: https://twitter.com/LeaVerou/status/356915789716135936

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox added support for `background-attachment: local` in version 25: http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/25.0/releasenotes/

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to set the element's `backgroundPosition` to correspond to the scroll offset of the element's content whenever it scrolls...

Keep in mind that you have to do this only when the browser doesn't support `background-attachment: local`, otherwise you'll mess up the scrolling really badly for the ones that do. Alternatively, stick with `background-attachment: scroll` and just do in JavaScript for all browsers.